# How can I send a property from Parent to Child?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have an odd issue where I can't access to props. I renamed all variables because it doesn't matter for the problem.

If I do `{{ myVar }}` the output is `{ "a": 1, "b": "Text1", "c": "Text2" }`. But if I use `{{ myVar.a }}` then I get the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $props.myVar is undefined`. Also the page is empty. But why is this?

I'm using Vue.js 3 with Composition API. In script setup of the CHILD I use this:

```
defineProps({
  myVar: Object
})
```

In template I want to use it via `{{ myVar.a }}`. The PARENT sends the property like this:

```
<MyModal v-show="isMyModalVisible" @close="closeMyModal()" :myVar="myVar"></MyModal>
```

What's wrong here? Is my access to the variable wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Lawrence Cherone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone) I used this solution now:

```
defineProps({
  myVar: { type: Object, default: new Object() }
});
```

This works. The reason for this is, that I set the variable `myVar` with the click event. Until then it's empty.